# Cant access Netgear Stora from Ubuntu 20.04.2.0

Tags: networking, storage

Just installed Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 on Lenovo B54000 OK but cant access my Netgear Stora. Can see the three basic folders ie. FamilyLibrary,MyComputers and MyLibrary but after attempting to open any folder and subsequently entering user name and password I just get an error code 50004. I know the Stora is working since I can access it fine from a Windows 10 desktop and an IPhone 6s app

Comment: Hi and welcome. That may be a better question for Netgear. https://community.netgear.com/t5/English/ct-p/English

Comment: How do you have the Stora mounted? `mount` will show. `sudo lsblk -f` will show what filesystems are there. If it's FAT, you can remount with `-o remount,rw,uid=$(id -u),gid=$(id -g)` option to `sudo mount`. Read `man mount lsblk id`.

Comment: Thanks all but it seems the problem is the Stora uses SMB1, but the latest download of Ubuntu does not. I had to install Samba then modify /etc/samba/smb.conf with the line "client min protocol = CORE "